# Problems enqueuing bootstrap in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am enqueuing bootstrap and this is my code:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','my_theme_enqueue_styles');

function my_theme_enqueue_styles(){

//Adding styles from my child-theme using get_stylesheet_directory_uri()
wp_enqueue_style('sydney-child-style',get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/style.css');

//Adding styles from my father-theme using get_template_directory_uri
wp_enqueue_style('sydney-style',get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css');
}

/**
 * Enqueue Bootstrap
 */
function sydney_enqueue_bootstrap() {
    wp_deregister_style('sydney-bootstrap');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'sydney-bootstrap-child', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css', array(), true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'sydney_enqueue_bootstrap', 9 );
```

The theme I am using is Sydney, and after doing a search in google and here I can't find out what is wrong. When I add bootstrap, I get a blank page and I can't see any content.
Any advise??, thank you in advance!

Comment: Any errrors? Are you sure the `get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css` is the correct path and name of file?

Comment: Probaly Bootstrap overrides some of the CSS in your theme so it breaks.

Comment: is the theme built using bootstrap?

Comment: yes it is using bootstrap and I tried using the get_template_directory_uri() and the get_style_directory_uri(). On the other hand, I dont get any error in the browser but I get the following error: 'Character encoding has not been declared'

Comment: sorry, I dont know what I have done but now is working. I think my original problem was in the add_action() function and when I copied and paste the code I overwrited some tags, but not sure because I have been crazy changeing and changeing the code. Thank you anyway!

Comment: however I think I am still having problems because style.css is overwritting bootstrap.css